# Difference between "Chiuahua" and "Chiuahueño"

Tags: selección-de-palabras

What is the difference between `Chiuahua` and `Chiuahueño`?? They both are/mean Chiuahua, the dog breed. Are there just other ways to say it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This wikipedia page](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chihuahue%C3%B1o_%28perro%29) claims that the *chihuahua* breed originated in Mexico. Elsewhere from Mexico the breed received the name of the state where this breed was found ([Chiuahua](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chihuahua), which means "arid and dusty land" in the language of the tarahumaras or rarámuris, a tribe native from Mexico) and it seems that in Mexico only the breed is also know as "chihuahueño".

That page doesn't have an English translation, but [this other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chihuahua_(dog)) explains more or less the same origin for the breed (except for the name *chihuahueño*).

So it seems that in Mexico only, *chihuahueño* refers to the name of the breed (and probably they use *Chihuahua* only to name the state). In Spain we use *"chihuahua"* and not *"chihuahueño"*. I don't know if there are any other countries in latin america which may also favor *"chihuahueño"* over *"chihuahua"* to refer to the dog breed.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very complete answer. If you will permit me, I would beg to advise you that _to ignore_ in English does not mean _not to know_ or _to be ignorant of_, but rather it has the meaning _no hacer caso de_, _desatender_, _pasar por alto_. Interestingly, though, _ignorant_ in English does mean pretty much _ignorante_ in Spanish.

Comment: @Animadversor, thanks to you for the correction. That was helpful.

Comment: I'm glad, Sir, to have been able to be of service while at the same time scratching my didactic itch.

Answer (score 5):

Having lived in Chihuahua, México for a time (20+ years ago), I observed the following...

`Chihuahua` - the name of the state

`Chihuahuense` - a person from the state of Chihuahua

`Chihuahueño` - the dog breed

Using *chihuahueño* to refer to a person was always either a joke or an insult.

As always, it's dangerous to assume that vocabulary used in one place can be generalized to all Spanish speakers. At least, several others from other parts of México with whom I worked used this vocabulary to make the distinction between the place, the person, and the perro.